# In R, can I include random effects in a censored regression?

Tags: r, random-effects-model, tobit-regression

I am comparing the consumption of algae given a treatment (5 levels) each at a unique site (N = 20). I deployed the same amount of algae at each site and assessed algal consumption by recording the amount of algae remaining at the end of the trial. Thus, the response is censored at the minimum consumption (0) and the maximum consumption (50 = length of algae at the start of the trial). There were multiple trials at each site (n = 2-4), and the length of the trial varied. I would like to incorporate site and the length of the trial as a random effect.

Comment: I would understand consumption to be a variable that is necessarily non-negative.  In what sense, then, do you think of it as being "censored" at zero? The sense in which you might view censoring occurring at 50 is understandable but it's not apparent that it's necessary to do that. Wouldn't it come down to the algae-consumption mechanism? If consumption rates depend on how much algae is left, for instance, then trying to model this as censoring at 50 might not be productive or accurate.

Comment: Maybe it is not censored at 0. The issue with the zeros is that they depend on the length of the trial. If the trial was run for longer, I could have observed some consumption. Perhaps I should not account for this by censoring.